# javascript load in mobile browser

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have applied this javascript in my website to hide a certain element when the browser width decreases in size.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $(window).bind("resize", function() {
            $('#slideshow').toggle($(this).width() >= 960);  
        }).trigger("resize");
    });
</script>
```

But in mobile browsers it displays the element quickly before removing it. Does anyone have any idea how to solve this?

Answer (score 1):

Your code doesn't run until the document is ready; meaning you'll see the element briefly until the `document.ready` method is fired in jQuery. You could take the code to hide the element and place it directly after the element, removing it from the `document.ready` wrapper.

```
<div id="slideshow"></div>
<script>
    $('#slideshow').toggle( $(window).width() >= 960 );
</script>
```

Alternatively, you could hide the element by default, and show it with JavaScript when the appropriate conditions are met.

```
<style>#slideshow { display: none }</style>

<div id="slideshow"></div>

<script>
    $('#slideshow').toggle( $(window).width() <= 960 );
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried twitter bootstrap solution for this?
http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/scaffolding.html